# How to create a text slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, text, slider

I am trying to create a text slider.
I am currently building a website and would like to add a section where I can display customer reviews and it changes from one review to another.

Comment: And what you try? Show some code...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with just HTML and CSS.
You would need to use Javascript, which assuming that you have this HTML:

```
 <div class="customer_review" id="review0">
   Some contents
 </div>
 ...
 <div class="customer_review" id="review14" style="display:none;">
   Some other contents
 </div>
```

Your Javascript would look something like:

```
var current_id = 0;

function newCustomerReview() {
  // get all review elements
  var reviews = document.getElementsByClassName("customer_review");
  current_id = (current_id < reviews.length) ? current_id++ : current_id = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < reviews.length; i++) {
    // iterate through every review element
    var myReview = reviews[i];
    // check if it is the new one we want
    if (i == current_id) {
      myReview.setAttribute("style", "display: block;");
      // or just remove style attribute
    }
    else {
      myReview.setAttribute("style", "display: none;");
    }
  }
  setTimeout("newCustomerReview();", 3000);
}

setTimeout("newCustomerReview();", 3000); // to start updating every 3 seconds
```